# Don't toggle if it is "on"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two buttons. When one of them is clicked, a gray box will show up and clicking the button again will send the box off stage.

I click on button 1, the gray box appears showing "button 1" inside it.

While the gray box is on stage, if I click on button 2, I want it remain on stage and show text "button 2", but the gray box goes off.

How can I keep it on stage and just change the text in the box?

```js
$('.clickMe').on("click", function() {
  var MyText = $(this).text();
  $('.gray-box').text(MyText).toggleClass('dock');
})
```

```css
.gray-box {
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: -120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dock {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='clickMe'>Button 1
 
 </button>
<p></p>
<button class='clickMe'>Button 2</button>

<div class="gray-box">
  My box
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hs1kut58/)

Comment: What do you want to remain on the page? The button? It stays visible. The gray box disappears. What is not working here?

Comment: try adding $(this).toggleClass('dock'); after your gray-box function and remove the .toggleClass('dock') from the end, is that what you are looking for? some more explanation if not.

Comment: When do you want the box to go "off stage"? I assume when the box says the name of the button you're clicking. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you only want to hide the box when it has the same text as the clicked button. I recommend comparing the text in the box to the text of the clicked button. If they are the same, toggle the box. If they are *not* the same, set the box text and make sure the box is showing.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
var $grayBox = $('.gray-box');

$('.clickMe').on("click", function() {

  // get the text of the clicked button
  var MyText = $(this).text();

  // if the box text is the same as the button text ...
  if (MyText == $grayBox.text()) {

    // ... toggle the box (in or out) ...
    $grayBox.toggleClass('dock');

  } else {

    // ... otherwise, set the box text and make sure it's showing.
    $grayBox.text(MyText).addClass('dock');

  }

})
```

```css
.gray-box {
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: -120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dock {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='clickMe'>Button 1
 
 </button>
<p></p>
<button class='clickMe'>Button 2</button>

<div class="gray-box">
  My box
</div>
```

---

### EDIT

Here's another method with more slightly more concise code.

Note that [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) accepts a `state` parameter.
The class will be added if `state` is `true` and removed if `state` is `false`.

> .toggleClass( className, state )

> **state**
>   Type: Boolean
>   A Boolean (not just truthy/falsy) value to determine whether the class should be added or removed.

Demonstration:

```js
var $grayBox = $('.gray-box');

$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {

  // get text of clicked button and box.
  var myText = $(this).text();
  var boxText = $grayBox.text();

  // "true" if text differs OR box is hidden. otherwise "false".
  var state = myText != boxText || $grayBox.not('.dock');

  // update the box text and state.
  $grayBox.text(myText).toggleClass('dock', state);

})
```

```css
.gray-box {
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: -120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dock {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='clickMe'>Button 1</button>
<button class='clickMe'>Button 2</button>
<div class="gray-box">My box</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, showdev very much, it works great in both methods!

Comment: Hi Showdev, I have another question related to this one.  Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56192855/jquery-2-divs-dock-and-un-dock

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear what you're asking here. But if you don't want the second click to toggle the class off, why don't you just use `addClass` instead? On click of either button, you can check to see if the gray box already has class `dock`, and if it doesn't, add it.

```js
$('.clickMe').on("click", function(){
  var MyText = $(this).text(),
      $GrayBox = $('.gray-box');
      
  $('.gray-box').text(MyText);
  if (!$GrayBox.hasClass('dock')) {
    $GrayBox.addClass('dock');
  }
});
```

```css
.gray-box {
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: -120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.dock {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='clickMe'>Button 1</button>
<p></p>
<button class='clickMe'>Button 2</button>
<div class="gray-box">My box</div>
```

Comment: Hi APAD1, Thank you very much for your sharing experience! and I didn't downvote for this, but I don't know why I got a downvote for mine by someone!