# Two divs dock and un-dock

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container box and a gray box, which is hidden from right side.  I also have 2 buttons. When one of them is clicked, the gray box will show up and will push the container box. When this button is clicked again, the gray box will move away out of stage by using `toggleClass` and the container box will expend back its wide.  That looks like dock and undock.

There is a logic here: When I click on button 1, the gray box appears showing "button 1" text inside it. WHILE the gray box is still on stage, if I click on button 2, "button 2" text will show on the gray box and it is still remain on stage.

Problem: When I click on the button 2 (as mentioning above), the container should be pushed by the gray box, but it expends while the gray box is still on stage.  The problem is on this JS `$('.container').toggleClass('col2 col1');`

```js
var $grayBox = $('.gray-box');

$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {

  // get text of clicked button and box.
  var myText = $(this).text();
  var boxText = $grayBox.text();

  // "true" if text differs OR box is hidden. otherwise "false".
  var state = myText != boxText || $grayBox.not('.dock');

  // update the box text and state.
  $grayBox.text(myText).toggleClass('dock', state);
  $('.container').toggleClass('col2 col1');
})
```

```css
.gray-box {
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: -120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dock {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.col1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col2 {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container col1">
  <p>
  </p>
  <button class='clickMe'>Button 1
     
     </button>
  <p></p>
  <button class='clickMe'>Button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="gray-box">
  My box
</div>
```

Please take a look at my sample on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ctrvpzk/1/)

Comment: I have tried `  if ( !$('.gay-box'.hasClass('dock'))) {
   $('.container').toggleClass('col2 col1');
  }
 else {
   $('.container').addClass('col2');
  }` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the class manipulation on `$grayBox` is dependent on `state`, it is not always a direct "toggle". For example, clicking a button might turn on the class, but clicking another button won't always turn it off. So the toggling of `col1 col2` can get out of sync with the state of `$graybox`.

I suggest using the `state` variable to change the width of `.container`. Also, instead of toggling two classes (`col1` and `col2`), I suggest only toggling one class that overrides the default style.

Below, I set the default width for `.container` to `100%`.
Toggling the `col2` class changes the width to `calc(100% - 120px)`.

```js
var $grayBox = $('.gray-box');
var $container = $('.container');

$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {

  // get text of clicked button and box.
  var myText = $(this).text();
  var boxText = $grayBox.text();

  // "true" if text differs OR box is hidden. otherwise "false".
  var state = myText != boxText || $grayBox.not('.dock');

  // update the box text and state.
  $grayBox.text(myText).toggleClass('dock', state);
  $container.toggleClass('col2', state);

});
```

```css
.gray-box {
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: -120px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dock {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 100%;
}

.col2 {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <p><button class='clickMe'>Button 1</button></p>
  <p><button class='clickMe'>Button 2</button></p>
</div>

<div class="gray-box">My box</div>
```

---

### Edit

Here's an experiment using a [flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```js
var $sideNav = $('#sideNav');

$('.navToggle').on('click', function() {

  // get text of clicked button and box.
  var btnText = $(this).text();
  var navText = $sideNav.text();

  // "true" if text differs OR box is hidden. otherwise "false".
  var state = btnText != navText || $sideNav.not('.open');

  // update the box text and state.
  $sideNav.text(btnText).toggleClass('open', state);

});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#buttons {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#sideNav {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  flex: 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sideNav.open {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="buttons">
    <p><button class='navToggle'>Button 1</button></p>
    <p><button class='navToggle'>Button 2</button></p>
  </div>
  <div id="sideNav">My box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi showdev, You are such a master! Thank you very much for explaining `sync` on this situation.  I am not quite understand about `toggleClass() accepts a state parameter`, in this case `$grayBox.text(myText).toggleClass('dock', state);`  Would you please explain how `state` here works?

Comment: Passing the `state` parameter is a way of controlling whether the class is added or removed. Usually, `toggleClass()` will add the class if it doesn't exist and will remove the class if it does exist. When you pass `state`, it works differently. If `state` is `true`, the class will be added. If `state` is `false`, the class will be removed. See [.toggleClass( className, state )](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state).

Comment: Hi ShowDev, Thank you very much for your explanation!